# Node.js and socket.io : Can not communicate server/client via Websocket

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I am new to node.js/socket.io/websocket and i am trying to create a web chat application. Currently i am stuck on 1 problem for days : no matter how hard i try i can't make the browser/server communication via websocket.

My server code :

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var port = 3700;

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

    console.log("Listening on port " + port);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("connect");
            socket.emit('globalmessage', { message: 'welcome to the chat !' });

            socket.on('send', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
            });
    });
```

My Client code :

```
        var messages = [];
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3700');
        var field = document.getElementById("field");
        var sendButton = document.getElementById("send");
        var content = document.getElementById("content");

        var name = 'test';
        var role = 1;

        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            if(data.message) {
                    messages.push(data);
                    var html = '';

                    for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
                            html += messages[i].message + '<br />';
                    }
                    content.innerHTML = html;
            } else {
                    console.log("There is a problem:", data);
            }
        });

        socket.on('globalmessage', function (data) {
            content.innerHTML += data.message;
        });     

        sendButton.onclick = function() {
            var text = field.value;
            socket.emit('send', { message: text, username: name, role: userrole});
        };
```

When i start node js server, and go to client via browser(both chrome and firefox) i got those data in cmd windows :

```
    info  - socket.io started
    Listening on port 3700
    debug - served static content /socket.io.js
    debug - client authorized
    info  - handshake authorized 7492ni4I5TCkRNvfG8WU
    debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/7492ni4I5TC
    debug - set heartbeat interval for client 7492ni4I5TCkRNvfG8WU
    debug - client authorized for
    debug - websocket writing 1::
    connect
    debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"globalmessage","args":[
    come to the chat !"}]}
    debug - emitting heartbeat for client 7492ni4I5TCkRNvfG8WU
    debug - websocket writing 2::
    debug - set heartbeat timeout for client 7492ni4I5TCkRNvfG8WU
```

As you can see, there are websocket writing 5:::{"name":"globalmessage","args":[ Welcome to the chat !"}]} so that mean the server can read when client is connected, and did emit the message back to client, but at client there are nothing happen, i can't read the message, the event is not fired at all. When i try to send message from client to server also nothing happen.

On firebug console i saw there are 1 success request to address

localhost:3700/socket.io/1/?t=1399976614584

with response **7492ni4I5TCkRNvfG8WU:60:60:websocket**

If i change the transport from websocket to xhr-polling everything work perfectly, the client can receive server message, can send back message to server, so i think the code is fine (actually i copied the code from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708 ).

So can you please help me on what's wrong with websocket setup at my local ? I have no idea what went wrong since everything work fine with ajax polling and i really need it to work with websocket instead. All my test was done in my local : windows 7 home premium, xampp 3.1.0 (websocket didn't work even if i turned apache off)

Thank you all !

Comment: So, when you click the `sendButton` nothing happen? I'll suggest to put some console.logs inside the `onclick` handler of the button and inside `socket.on('message'` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I have used socket io with express on a project before, but i have never had this issue. I can share the code that i have with you which this

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var io_connection = io.listen(server, {
origins: '*:*',
log: true,
'heartbeat timeout': 6000,
'close timeout': 6000,
'log level': 3,
'transports': [
  'websocket',
  'flashsocket',
  'htmlfile',
  'xhr-polling',
  'jsonp-polling'
]
});

io_connection
.on('connection', function(socket) {
  user(socket); // bind user socket connection
  poll(socket); // bind user's socket to poll related sockets

 });

return io;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for reply, i tried your code but it's still didn't work, this time the server didn't emit the message to client as well. I use socket.emit('globalmessage', { message: 'welcome to the chat !' }); on .on('connection instead of user(socket) and poll(socket) (i guess they are your function?)

Comment: sorry, you need to take out user(socket), this is another file that i used to bind those socket to their respective listeners. have you tried to put in the listeners into the on('connection')?

Comment: Hi eugene i guess user(socket) is your function so i did take it out, but it still can't work for me. I am trying to host my apps on heroku now to see if i can make it work via websocket there.

Comment: sorry @Mir, that's weird to me. alright, all the best :D